# make ntfs hdd only visible in Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, partitioning

Is it possible to create or make a ntfs partition that only visible in Ubuntu/linux? 
and how do we make it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to hide it in Windows?

Comment: Hide it from who? Root ? someone who boots a live USB ? The only way to "hide" information is to encrypt it.

Comment: @Cornelius Sorry for not unclear. Like you said. Hide it in windows, so we can open it only in ubuntu

Comment: Hiding it will be quite hard since you seem to want a 'real NTFS'  filesystem on the drive. However depending on your goal you could just not assign a drive letter under windows.

Comment: How about change the partition code? I have seen my friend had ntfs filesystem, but it has linux partition type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the partition's type code using `fdisk` (or `gdisk` for GPT disks). Specifically, the `t` command in these programs enables you to change the type code. Change it from 07 to 83 (for MBR/`fdisk`) or from 0700 to 8300 (for GPT/`gdisk`). This will hide the partition from view in Windows.

That said, I don't recommend doing as you suggest. NTFS is a Windows filesystem, not a Linux filesystem, so if you want to use a partition in Linux but not in Windows, there are no advantages to using NTFS and lots of disadvantages, including:

- Lack of support for Linux-style file ownership.
- Lack of support for Linux-style permissions.
- Poor performance compared to Linux-native filesystems.
- Lack of filesystem maintenance tools.

Instead, use a Linux-native filesystem for Linux. Unless you install the relevant driver, Windows will then be unable to read that filesystem (although it could damage or destroy it, given enough malice, persistence, or bad luck).

Also, given your responses to earlier suggestions, I think you need to clarify precisely what your intent is in this. So long as a disk is plugged into a computer, there's really nothing you can do to completely safeguard data on that disk from tampering by whatever OS is currently running on the computer. If you want that sort of safeguard, the only acceptable solution is to unplug the disk. If you just want to avoid accidental damage or unauthorized access by relative computer novices, changing the type code or removing the drive letter (as Cornelius suggested) should suffice.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Just ask, because my friend had a ntfs partition but windows can't read it...

Comment: If Windows can't read an NTFS partition, then that's probably a Windows problem, although it could have a cause of an incorrect partition type. I recommend asking on a Windows forum, and providing partitioning details from Windows partitioning tools.

Answer (score 1):

Right click `My Computer`, select `Manage` and `Disk Management`.

Right click the partition, select `Change Drive Letters and Paths` then remove the drive letter.

[image]

This just hides the partition! It doesn't make it not accessible though.

Comment: Thanks, but i really want to make it inaccessible from windows. Any way?